Sci-Fi/Fantasy movie with character who can control the future?
I'm looking for the name of a movie, on behalf of a friend.  Here is all the information I have so far:

Some time ago (like 8 years ago) I saw a movie where one of the characters is a weird guy (not so sure, but I think he had something like a music box with him) that does nothing almost the entire movie, close to the end, the guy turns out to be a guy who can synchronize causality by just triggering one event. 
  I recall that he threw something on the street, then some one slipped, and then something else happens,and so and so. Finally at the end of all those things the girl got the guy or the guy got the girl.
Some characters appear to help the main one.  One of the characters is a guy who seems to hear lots of voices and sounds all at the time and can't make anything like of it, he looks like totally mentally ill. Finally when its time for him to work he makes sense of all the voices and knows that by throwing water or whatever in the floor a series of events will happen in order to make the happy ending.

Other info that I have:

Language: English
Year of release: Most likely between 2000 and 2010
Movie was in color


The 'music box' and causing a chain of events sounds kind of like what Jacob does in this scene from Ink (2009).

I haven't seen it, so probably this won't be it, but the music box part reminded me of the movie The Box...

@Walt, your guess is correct if you'd like to post it as a proper answer.

@user23400 No problem.

You're looking for Ink, an independent sci-fi film from 2009.

When we go to sleep, two forces battle for our dreams: the Storytellers, who give us good dreams; and the Incubi, who give us nightmares. Widower John Sullivan is estranged from his young daughter Emma, having been deemed unable to care for her. [...] a mysterious stranger named Ink snatches little Emma from her bed and escapes into the dream world, intent on selling her soul to the Assembly of the Incubi so that he may be allowed entry into their ranks. A small band of Storytellers realizes that the only way to save Emma is to reunite her with her father in the physical world, and they will do anything to make sure that this comes to pass. 

One of the Storytellers is Jacob, who can tap into the "beat of the world" and causes a chain of events in this scene with the help of an odd-looking music box:



It's quite reminiscent of Spin, a short film from 2005 by Ink's creators in which a man uses a turntable to change events (this time to prevent an accident):



